# CSS - можно ли написать .css файл, который применяется ТОЛЬКО для другого .css файла? Подробности внутри

Tags: css

Мне нужно написать стили, которые МЕНЯЮТ стили .css файла (1), но не влияют на стили других .css файлов (2, 3, 4, 5...).

Вот подробное описание того, что я хочу сделать.
Есть уже написанные стили CSS. Я хочу для определенного раздела (селектор по id) обнулить их. И написать свои. 
Под словом "обнулить" я понимаю вот такой сброс.

Было:

```
float: left;
```

Обнуление:

```
float: none;
```

Проблема в том, что float: none будет применяться и к моим стилям. То есть, моим стилям придется дописывать селектор по id, чтобы перекрыть это обнуление. 
Возможно ли написать обнуление ТОЛЬКО для одного CSS файла - уже написанных стилей? Чтобы оно не задевало мои стили? Чтобы мне не пришлось дописывать к моим стилям селектор по id (для перекрытия обнуления).
В моем распоряжении и JS и PHP.

Comment: А почему просто не добавить `float: left !important;` у себя, чтобы убрать обнуление?

Comment: Выкиньте из головы файлы, браузеру пофиг в каком файле какое правило написано, имеют значения только селекторы, их порядок и вес

Comment: @Darth, вес...?

Comment: @Yuri, с таким же успехом можно в своем файле добавить селектор по id к своим селекторам и перекрыть. Я хочу без редактирования своего файла. Просто объем кода очень большой, нужно очень много редактировать, легко можно что-то случайно пропустить, не усмотреть. Да и селекторы тогда будут выглядеть длинными очень.

Comment: @Yuri http://css.yoksel.ru/specifity/

Comment: редактируйте не вручную, а при помощи какой-нибудь утилиты - PostCSS, например.

Comment: А если сделать файл с такими же названиями стилей как и в файле 1, но с обнуленными значениями, и подключить их в порядке: файл1, файл-обнулятор, а дальше свои файлы со стилями. Единственное тут могут быть ошибки, если в обнуляторе будут приоритеты выше, чем в последующих файлах

Comment: @Sergey Glazirin, именно в этом и проблема.

Comment: Я могу ошибаться но если у вас на разных страницах используются разные css файлы вы можете в нужный сss файл добавить свой файл с перекрытиями использую импорт  @import "/style/main.css"

Comment: @Broouzer King, а как быть с popup окошком - плагином на JS? Там должны быть старые стили. А у меня они не подключены. Окошко ведь на той же странице открывается.

Comment: @Alexandr Nevajno, как как - окуратно, в принципе ответ  ниже  абсолютно верный 100% иделаьного и безболезненного способа вы не найдете, можете комбинировать рекомендации полученные здесь для выработки своего максимально подходящего способа, но обойти без перелопачивания всего вашего кода вам все равно в той ил иной степени не удастся

Answer (score 2):

Можно через родительский класс попробовать переопределить стили. Пока файлы и разметку не увижу более подробно — ничего другого порекомендовать не могу. Но лучше при верстке и стилизации использовать классы.

```css
#text {
  color: red;
}

.parent #text {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"> <!-- <- -->  
  <div id="text">Hello, World!</div>
</div>
```

---

**И что значит переопределить в одном файле, игнорирую другой?**

Если у вас в первом файле:

```
.class {
    color: red;
}
```

Во втором файле:

```
.class {
    color: blue;
}
```

А вы хотите переопределить как (третьим файлом)?

```
.class {
    color: green;
}
```

В результате всё-равно правила из первого и второго файла переопределяться. Но если вы свой третий файл со стилями «вставите» перед вторым — второй в результате переопределить ваш третий. Следуя принципам наследования и каскадирования... На то они и [Cascading Style Sheets](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS#.D0.9D.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5._.D0.9A.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5._.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.8B_.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B9_CSS.).

---

#### CSS Encapsulation

Возможно вариант решения подойдет как это делается в стилях для компонентов в Angular — [CSS Encapsulation with Angular Components](https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-encapsulation-with-angular-components) или [Appendix: Inspecting generated CSS](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#appendix-inspecting-generated-css).

А именно обратите внимание на этот блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или

```css
[_nghost-pmm-5] {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h3[_ngcontent-pmm-6] {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
```

```html
<hero-details _nghost-pmm-5>
  <h2 _ngcontent-pmm-5>Mister Fantastic</h2>
  <hero-team _ngcontent-pmm-5 _nghost-pmm-6>
    <h3 _ngcontent-pmm-6>Team</h3>
  </hero-team>
</hero-detail>
```

---

**P.S.** Вообщем вы сталнкулить с проблемой что верстку изначально нужно правильно организовывать.

Comment: Задача - интегрировать новую верстку в интернет-магазин. Там есть стили для карточек с товарами. Мне нужно изменить их. Проблема в том, что изменить нужно только для раздела с каталогом товаров. А для остальных (карточки там тоже выводятся - в виде "Вы недавно смотрели" или "Похожие товары" и тд...) оставить.
Мне бы подошел отрицательный селектор (как в JQuery) - применить стили для всех разделов, но не для каталога. Кажется, в CSS есть такой (я не пробовал его использовать, поэтому точно про его действие сказать не могу), но у него очень плохая поддержка.

Comment: Я хочу в разделе каталога товаров отключить старые стили, чтобы без их переопределения добавить свои. Проблема переопределения в том, что у некоторых элементов очень длинные селекторы, из-за чего приоритет высокий. Если переопределять (обнулять), то в новых стилях мне придется "перебивать" этот приоритет - либо дописанием к своим стилям еще селекторов, либо использованием !imporant (а мне не хочется этого делать).

Comment: Можно было бы использовать PHP - в зависимости от url (страница каталога, другая страница) подключать или не подключать стили (которые заранее перенесены в другой файл). Но стили должны работать в popup-окне от JS (быстрый просмотр товара). А popup-окно открывается на той же странице. Поэтому я писал "раздел", а не "страница".

Comment: @AlexandrNevajno а вы бы не могли в вопрос разметку с карточками товаров добавить + отдельно блок «Вы недавно смотрели». Или есть сайт запущен — ссылку просто дать. Нам будет проще соориентироваться над проблемой.

Comment: @AlexandrNevajno дополнил ответ блоком CSS Encapsulation.

Comment: @AlexandrNevajno опять таки: всё это догадки, пока мы фактическую разметку не увидим и файлы с CSS-стилями.